# How to determine coordinates of an element with Watir Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have a problem. While parsing a page, a pop-up window appears and blocks access to html. I tried to click on the pop-up, but it re-directs me to a new page, and I have no clue how to get to the upper right area of the pop-up to close it. My question is how to determine the coordinates of that element? None of the related issues raised here at Stackoverflow helped me find a solutions, so assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I do not have access to html, all i have is a screen! Is there an oppotunity to share a screen here? I am new to Stackoverflow!

Comment: The developer tools in the browser should let you see the HTML, and inspection tools that will let you see what's going on. 
Odds are that's not really a window, just a Div or some other element that is covering up the other stuff.   If you are trying to create automation, you REALLY need to have access to the HTML, screenshots will lack critical info you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the actual coordinates? That seems like a bad idea given it could move or have different results on different screen sizes (responsive designs). You'd be better off finding the class / id of the close button and calling `browser.button(class: 'close').click` or `browser.link(class: 'close').click`.

If you need help determining the class of the close button, open your browser and enable developer tools / console. They all have an inspector tool now to select the element and find all classes & ids.

In the unlikely event there are no classes or ids it may have a `data` attribute you could work off.

Comment: I do not have access to the element, this is the problem - I cannot find the right upper cross to close it. I can click on the element itself, but it redirects me to a new page.

Comment: Because of this pop-up most elements on the page are hidden

Comment: define 'do not have access to', wait are you talking about a modal pop-up like http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#static-example ? Or are you actually talking about an alert / confirmation dialog https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_alert ?

Comment: if it's an alert use this: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Alert
Only one alert can be active on a page at a time and there's an `exists?` method to check you're not trying to close something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I am writing a parser for a banking page. I do not have the credentials to a page and write the parser using the screenshots that I have. On one of them I have a normal page, while on the next one - a message which I cannot address. 

    browser.alert.exists?   shows false

Comment: This is why I am asking about the coordinates, as nothing else has worked. Indeed, coordinates is far not the best solution given the fact that a responsive page would cause the solution fail, but still, I see no other options at the moment.

Comment: If you can open it in a web browser you have access to the html. If you're doing it in watir, as you claim, you have access to the html and other items. Work out if it's an alert or pop-up, re: my question above, then go from there. Coordinates aren't an option that Watir supports from what I can see. And even if it did to calculate the coordinates you'd need the element to get the css which contains the location.

Comment: Watir supports coordinates. What I have at my disposal is a png screen, and an html which lacks css.

Comment: I am now trying a different solution:
  
  
  browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('modal_tarjetas')[0].remove();")

Comment: 'modal_tarjetas' there's the class I was asking for

Comment: As long as the pop-up is present, none of the elements with this class could be accessed. I am now trying to remove the script, will report how it goes.

Comment: If you were restricted to screenshots, and not able to work with a live page, I'd say you were setup to fail.   To do automation at the HTML level you need to be able to see the HTML.  otherwise you're really just kinda flailing around like a blindfolded person trying to hit a pinata.

Answer (score 0):

If the pop-up is a regular browser window you can close it by index. Your main window has index 0. So the pop-up has index 1.

```
if browser.window(:index => 1).exists?
     browser.window(:index => 1).close
end
```

Comment: This one didn't work as well because there was an overflow hidden, which I managed to get rid of by running a JS pluggin. Afterwards a simple "browser.alert.ok" worked just fine. Though, thank you for your answer!